# Open dialog modal from material-ui using dataprovider with react and dynamic table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a dynamic table that is using react hooks, useEffect, useState and DataTypeProvider.
The table is from the `@devexpress/dx-react-grid`

I have an edit column on my table and I am using the dataprovider component to manipulate the data from a specific column.

```
const EditProvider = props => (
    <DataTypeProvider
        formatterComponent={({ row }) => (
            <Button
                onClick={() => (
                    <Dialog>
                        <DialogContent>
                            <DialogContentText>
                               {row.log}
                            </DialogContentText>
                        </DialogContent>
                    </Dialog>
                )}
            >
                EDIT
            </Button>
        )}
        {...props}
    />
);
```

What I am trying to achieve is that when I click the Edit button on a row, a modal window to be opened.

I am using the material-ui for the dialog window.

If instead of the Dialog compoenent I try to execute an alert(row.log) function, everything words.

The code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import FiberManualRecordIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FiberManualRecord';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';

import {
    GroupingState,
    IntegratedGrouping,
    FilteringState,
    IntegratedFiltering,
    SortingState,
    IntegratedSorting,
    DataTypeProvider,
} from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid';

import {
    Grid,
    Table,
    TableHeaderRow,
    TableGroupRow,
    GroupingPanel,
    DragDropProvider,
    Toolbar,
    TableFilterRow,
    TableColumnResizing,
} from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui';


const EditProvider = props => (
    <DataTypeProvider
        formatterComponent={({ row }) => (
            <Button
                onClick={() => (
                    <Dialog>
                        <DialogContent>
                            <DialogContentText>
                               {row.log}
                            </DialogContentText>
                        </DialogContent>
                    </Dialog>
                )}
            >
                EDIT
            </Button>
        )}
        {...props}
    />
);

const FilterIcon = ({ type, ...restProps }) => {
    return <TableFilterRow.Icon type={type} {...restProps} />;
};

export default props => {
    const [columns] = useState([
        { name: 'edit', title: 'Edit' },
        { name: 'log', title: 'Description' },
    ]);

    const [defaultColumnWidths] = useState([
        { columnName: 'edit', width: 75 },
        { columnName: 'log', width: 450 },
    ]);

    const [rows, setTableRow] = React.useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTableRow(props.info);
    }, [props.info]);

    const [filteringColumnExtensions] = useState([
        {
            predicate: (value, filter, row) => {
                if (!filter.value.length) return true;
                return IntegratedFiltering.defaultPredicate(value, filter, row);
            },
        },
    ]);


    return (
        <Paper>
            <Grid rows={rows} columns={columns}>
             
                <IntegratedSorting />
                <DragDropProvider />
                <GroupingState/>
                <IntegratedGrouping />
                <FilteringState defaultFilters={[]} />
                <IntegratedFiltering
                    columnExtensions={filteringColumnExtensions}
                />
                <EditProvider for={['edit']} />
                <Table />
                <TableColumnResizing
                    defaultColumnWidths={defaultColumnWidths}
                />
                <TableHeaderRow showSortingControls />
                <TableGroupRow />
                <Toolbar />
                <GroupingPanel showSortingControls />
                <TableFilterRow showFilterSelector iconComponent={FilterIcon} />
            </Grid>
        </Paper>
    );
};
```

Comment: No way it could work like this. You cannot return jsx from function and hopping it will be added to DOM :) So you have to use a `state`, onClick you set your state with the row, and depending on your state, you open your Dialog, which is already returned with your datalist